# How many word2vec pretrained models are available?

Tags: natural-language, word-embeddings, word2vec

In my experiments with pre-trained *word2vec* models for *NLP* tasks, I have so far come across two models - one trained on Google News dataset and another which has been trained on Wikipedia text corpus.

Are there other pre-trained models available for the extraction of *word2vec* embedding ?

Google search on this issue only comes up with FastText, *sentence2vec* models etc.

Moreover, can a *sentence2vec* embedding (obtained from the same dataset) be used as an alternative to *word2vec* embedding (by naively assuming that the sentence contains only one word)?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ? Get an embedding word in order to process a classification ? Get a representation of your sentences ?

Comment: @Kledou exactly. I just want to get a representation for some words from a pre-trained word2vec model for classification tasks

Comment: (A) Do you specifically want English embeddings? (B) Why do you particularly want word2vec, as opposed to some other embedding of the word types? Without more information, pre-trained GloVe or FastText embeddings probably suit your needs as well. [They’re all approximations to the same function](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/2020.emnlp-main.681/).

Comment: There are a lot.  What I would also add to the list is GloVe https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/.

Answer (score 0):

There are several available models, you can check this:
https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim-data